# Testing WML on mobile browsers

Tags: html, testing, mobile, wml

I am developing a mobile web application which is implemented in `WML` (to minimize roundtrips to the server).

I've tested the application on the following browsers:

- `IE for Windows Mobile 5`
- `IE for Windows Mobile 6`
- `Opera Mobile`
- `Nokia Series 40` web browser
- `Nokia Series 60` web browser
- `NetFront` (for `Symbian`)
- `NetFront` (for `Sony Ericsson`)
- `NetFront` (for `Samsung`)
- `Fly SX210` (don't know neither platform nor browser name, `HTTP_USER_AGENT` says `FLY-SX210/Profile/MIDP.2.0Configuration/CLDC.1.0`)

`IPhone` does not support `WML`, I use `IUI` for `IPhone` instead.

What else widely used mobile browsers should I test the application with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only big one I think your missing is the Verizon HTML Browser, standered on most touch screen phones Verizon has.